# Regex exclude number

Tags: regex

I have regex pattern `(\s\w+(\W\w+|)\s)|(\s\w+\s)` it parse sequence that contain `(string,mfo,system.int32,0,...)`. How to rewrite pattern in such way that `(0)` will be excluded?

```
account :type string :init "" :display "account"
mfo :type string :init "" :display "mfo"
name :type string :init "" :display "name"
city :type string :init "" :display "city"
tag :type system.int32 :init 0 :display ""
domain :type string :init "" :display "domain"
name :type string :init "" :display "name"
multiplier :type system.int32 :init 0
```

Comment: What are your trying to achieve here? The negative lookahead will probably not do what you want.

Comment: Your question is unclear.  What does your sample data look like?  What do you want to extract or validate?

Comment: @RudyTheHunter, "I am trying to get all string and system.int32" from data that you can see in post.

Comment: Please read this:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  Think like a developer.  What is your requirement, what is your input data, what is the desired output?  Show us that information.

Comment: Looks to me that you want both the name and the type. In that case you could use `(\w+).*:type ([.\w]+)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following expression will filter your lines on type `string` or `system.int32`, the first group `$1` holds the values at the end of the line:

```
type
\ 
(?:string|system\.int32)
.+?"?([^"]*)"?$
```

See [a demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/cS2xJ4/2). Is this what you were after?